# Possible approaches for iteration over multiple lists using python dataframe or any library

Tags: python, list, iteration

I want to write a Python program which iterates multiple lists and gets all the possible combinations of each element. I will illustrate the idea in greater detail below.

I have three lists as following:

```
list_01=['A','B','C','D']
list_02=[2, 2.5, 3, 3.5]
list_03=['2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008']
```

And I would like to obtain the following output:

```
A,2,2003
A,2,2004
A,2,2005
A,2,2006
A,2,2007
...
...
...
D,3.5,2006
D,3.5,2007
D,3.5,2008
```

Is there a solution for this task? Thank you so much.

Comment: In general when one answer solves the question, the author of the Question (sometimes on Stack Overflow the author of the question is called OP that stands for *Original Poster*) accepts it. In this case your question receives two answer. If at least one of these solves your problem, please Accept it with the `V` symbol on the left.

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know about that. However I have not find the V symbol on the left. Will you mind elaborate that?

Comment: I refer to the symbol which is on the top left of every Answers and that is used to accept the answer. If you read something about Stack Overflow, for example the Tour that you find in the Question Mark (?) in the top left of the page, you will discover that accepting an answer is one of the most important action for correctly using the site. If you accept an answer you earn 2 points of reputation and who answer earns 15 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 3 nested loops

You can use the code below:

```
list_01=['A','B','C','D']
list_02=[2, 2.5, 3, 3.5]
list_03=['2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008']

for k in list_01:
    for j in list_02:
        for i in list_03:
            print(k+','+str(j) + ',' + i)
```

In the code the instruction: `print(k+','+str(j) + ',' + i)` manages the integer content of `list_02` by the conversion `str(j)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. As the previous answer, you guys saved me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We can approach this with nested for loops.

```
list_01=['A','B','C','D']
list_02=[2, 2.5, 3, 3.5]
list_03=['2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008']

for i in range(len(list_01)): 
    for j in range(len(list_02)): 
        for k in range(len(list_03)): 
            print(list_01[i], list_02[j], list_03[k], sep = ',', end = ' ')
```

Once the third for loop goes through each value of list 3 by incrementing k each time the loop repeats, 'j', our iterator for list 2, increases by one, and we go through each value of list 3 again, this time, with the second element of list 2. From there, the same thing happens, but this time with the next element of the first list.